# Reshape a pandas DataFrame using combination of row values in two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data for multiple customers in data frame as below-

```
Customer_id     event_type  month   mins_spent
1               live        CM          10
1               live        CM1         10
1               catchup     CM2         20
1               live        CM2         30

2               live        CM          45
2               live        CM1         30
2               catchup     CM2         20
2               live        CM2         20
```

I need the result data frame so that there is one row for each customer and column are combined value of column month and event_type and value will be mins_spent. Result data frame as below-

```
Customer_id     CM_live CM_catchup  CM1_live    CM1_catchup CM2_live    CM2_catchup
1               10      0           10          0           30              20
2               45      0           30          0           20              20
```

Is there an efficient way to do this instead of iterating the input data frame and creating the new data frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pivot_table`

```
# pivot your data frame
p = df.pivot_table(values='mins_spent', index='Customer_id',
                   columns=['month', 'event_type'], aggfunc=np.sum)

# flatten multi indexed columns with list comprehension
p.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in p.columns]

             CM_live  CM1_live  CM2_catchup  CM2_live
Customer_id                                          
1                 10        10           20        30
2                 45        30           20        20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column (`key`) by concatenating columns `month` and `event_type`, and then use `pivot()` to reshape your data.

```
(df.assign(key = lambda d: d['month'] + '_' + d['event_type'])
  .pivot(
    index='Customer_id',
    columns='key',
    values='mins_spent'
  ))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.